# pandas read_csv: The error_bad_lines argument has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read some data which may sometimes have erroneous and bad rows, so as always I passed `error_bad_lines=False` but the console keeps throwing the deprecation warning on every run. Why is this feature deprecated and is there any other alternative for skipping bad lines?

Comment: Which function do you use? `read_csv`?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> Deprecated since version 1.3.0: The on_bad_lines parameter should be used instead to specify behavior upon encountering a bad line instead.

So, replace:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(..., error_bad_lines=False)
```

with:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(..., on_bad_lines='skip')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to make it even more clear, if you use `error_bad_lines` and `warn_bad_lines`, both should be replaced by `on_bad_lines`.

Comment: @ruhanbidart. Right you can replace `error_bad_lines=True` by `on_bad_lines='error'` and `warn_bad_lines=True` by `on_bad_lines='warn'`

Comment: Thanx for this excellent punchline ;-)