# TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'

Tags: python, pandas, bash

I have multiple sets of files in the current directory and the unique ID of each file is the substring before the first `.` parenthesis. For example, the ID for `A001C007.log` is `A001C007`.

For each ID, I want to run the following experiment on the set of respective files.

Note: I do not have write access to the source code and therefore cannot amend `pd.read_csv(...,error_bad_lines=False)`

```
for id in *.log; do
  annotate-gene-fusion --sv-file "${id%.CNN_SVs.5K_combined.txt}" \
                       --output-file "${id%.gene-fusions.txt}" \
                       --buff-size 10000 --skip-rows 1 --ensembl-release 93 --species human
done
```

Traceback:

```
INFO:pyensembl.database:Creating database: /home/melchua/.cache/pyensembl/GRCh38/ensembl93/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.93.gtf.db
INFO:pyensembl.database:Reading GTF from /home/melchua/.cache/pyensembl/GRCh38/ensembl93/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.93.gtf.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/bin/annotate-gene-fusion", line 97, in <module>
    run()
  File "/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/bin/annotate-gene-fusion", line 61, in run
    db.index()
  File "/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyensembl/genome.py", line 275, in index
    self.db.connect_or_create(overwrite=overwrite)
  File "/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyensembl/database.py", line 291, in connect_or_create
    return self.create(overwrite=overwrite)
  File "/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyensembl/database.py", line 213, in create
    df = self._load_gtf_as_dataframe(
  File "/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyensembl/database.py", line 605, in _load_gtf_as_dataframe
    df = read_gtf(
  File "/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtfparse/read_gtf.py", line 208, in read_gtf
    result_df = parse_gtf_and_expand_attributes(
  File "/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtfparse/read_gtf.py", line 151, in parse_gtf_and_expand_attributes
    result = parse_gtf(
  File "/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtfparse/read_gtf.py", line 82, in parse_gtf
    chunk_iterator = pd.read_csv(
TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
```

I tried to use pandas version 1.4.0 but the error persisted.

```
pip install --user 'pandas==1.4.0'

Collecting pandas==1.4.0
  Using cached pandas-1.4.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.7 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in /scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/envs/EagleC/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas==1.4.0) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/envs/EagleC/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas==1.4.0) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in /scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/envs/EagleC/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas==1.4.0) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/envs/EagleC/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas==1.4.0) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: pandas
Successfully installed pandas-1.3.5
```

Example files in the current directory (for `A001C007`, `A001C008`, and `A002C012` samples):

```
A001C007.CNN_SVs.10K_highres.txt  A002C010.CNN_SVs.5K_combined.txt
A001C007.CNN_SVs.10K.txt      A002C010.CNN_SVs.5K.txt
A001C007.CNN_SVs.50K_highres.txt  A002C010.log
A001C007.CNN_SVs.50K.txt      A002C012.CNN_SVs.10K_highres.txt
A001C007.log              A002C012.CNN_SVs.10K.txt
A001C008.CNN_SVs.10K_highres.txt  A002C012.CNN_SVs.50K_highres.txt
A001C008.CNN_SVs.10K.txt      A002C012.CNN_SVs.50K.txt
A001C008.CNN_SVs.50K_highres.txt  A002C012.CNN_SVs.5K_combined.txt
A001C008.CNN_SVs.50K.txt      A002C012.CNN_SVs.5K.txt
A001C008.log              A002C012.log
```

Expected output:

As per the [software](https://github.com/XiaoTaoWang/EagleC), a run for a single set of files with ID `SK-N-AS` would be:

```
annotate-gene-fusion --sv-file SK-N-AS.CNN_SVs.5K_combined.txt \
                       --output-file SK-N-AS.gene-fusions.txt \
                       --buff-size 10000 --skip-rows 1 --ensembl-release 93 --species human
```

Comment: The code is apparently trying to use the `error_bad_lines` parameter inside `pd.read_csv`, but that one has been deprecated since `pd` version `1.3.0`. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69513799/18470692).

Comment: Update your gtfparse. It has a check-in on Dec 17th (2022 I presume) to fix.

Comment: I've updated `gtfparse` but the error persisted.

Comment: @ouroboros1 I can't update the source code. It's not written by me. I can only manipulate the command line.

Comment: Maybe try installing the latest version of `gtfparse`? (`pip install -U gtfparse`). In the latest version, it looks like they've updated to using polars instead of pandas. Oh someone already recommended the same thing. Well, are you sure you updated? Because the latest version doesn't even have the `chunk_iterator` variable in the source code anywhere. You could also open and edit manually the source code for gtfparse. Open `/scg/apps/software/eaglec/0.1.9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtfparse/read_gtf.py` and edit the line which is throwing the pandas error (remove the `error_bad_lines`).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have root access to either update `gtfparse` or replace the `error_bad_lines`. Any other solutions will be welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

try using the os module:

```
import os

def run_experiment(id):
    sv_file = f"{id}.CNN_SVs.5K_combined.txt"
    output_file = f"{id}.gene-fusions.txt"
    command = (f"annotate-gene-fusion --sv-file {sv_file} "
               f"--output-file {output_file} "
               f"--buff-size 10000 --skip-rows 1 --ensembl-release 93 --species human")
    os.system(command)

ids = set(filename.split('.')[0] for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.endswith('.log'))

for id in ids:
    run_experiment(id)
```

Comment: I can't update the source code. It's not written by me. I can only manipulate the command line